# Provider parse errors: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef_: in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule

Tags: angular, typescript, module, circular-reference

i am trying to implement the APP_INITIALIZER into my app.Module to load the config before the App starts. My app has a main module "AppModule", submodules under AppModule and global module for shared Services between main module and submodules:

AppModule:

```js
//Modules
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DevExtremeModule } from 'devextreme-angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { SharedModule } from './modules/shared/module';

//Services
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { NavigationGuard } from './Helper/navigationGuard';
import { AppService } from './services/app.service';


//Components
import { NavigationComponent } from './components/navigation/navigation.component';
import { ActionBarComponent } from './components/actionBar/actionBar.component';
import { ModulesMenuComponent } from './components/modulesMenu/modulesMenu.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { DashboardDetailComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboardDetail.component';
import { DashboardMachineSelectComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboardMachineSelect.component';
import { ConfigurationComponent } from './components/configuration/configuration.component';

//Direktiven
import { ClickOutsideDirective } from './Directives/clickOutside.directive';


//Pipes
import { ValuesPipe } from './Pipes/KeyValuesPipe';
import { PercentPipe} from './Pipes/PercentPipe';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
  //Modules
  DevExtremeModule,
  BrowserModule,
  HttpModule,
  JsonpModule,
  FormsModule,
  RouterModule,
  routing,
  SharedModule.forRoot()
 ],
 declarations: [

  //Components
  AppComponent,
  NavigationComponent,
  DashboardComponent,
  DashboardDetailComponent,
  DashboardMachineSelectComponent,
  ModulesMenuComponent,
  ConfigurationComponent,
  ActionBarComponent,

  //Pipes
  ValuesPipe,
  PercentPipe,

  //Direktiven
  ClickOutsideDirective
 ],
 providers: [NavigationGuard,
  AppService,
  {
   provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
   useFactory: (configService: AppService) => function ()
   {
    return configService.initializeConfig()
   },
   deps: [AppService],
   multi: true
  }],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

SharedModule:

```js
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from '../../Services/app.service';

@NgModule({})
/**
 * Gemeinsames Modul welches in der ganzen App verwendet werden kann. Beinhaltet alle zu teilenden Elemente
 */
export class SharedModule {

 /**
 * Überschriebene forRoot Funktion zum Teilen von gemeinsamen Elementen
 */
 static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
  return {
   ngModule: SharedModule,
   providers: [AppService]
  }
 }
}
```

Since i added this Code:

```js
providers: [NavigationGuard,
  AppService,
  {
   provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
   useFactory: (configService: AppService) => function ()
   {
    return configService.initializeConfig()
   },
   deps: [AppService],
   multi: true
  }],
```

i get this Error:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Provider parse errors:
>   Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef_: in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error:

I've tried to put the function in to a constructor of the Module and call the fuction without AppService. Without AppService it works fine, but i need to access the service to load the configuration.

AppService:

```js
import { Inject, Injectable, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { Router, NavigationEnd, } from '@angular/router';
import { AppSettings } from '../Models/AppSettings';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ModuleItem } from '../Helper/ModuleItem';
import { NavItem } from '../Helper/NavItem';
import { ActionBarItem } from '../Helper/actionBarItem';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'; 

export { ModuleItem } from '../Helper/ModuleItem';
export { NavItem } from '../Helper/NavItem';
export { ActionBarItem } from '../Helper/actionBarItem';
export { AppSettings } from '../Models/AppSettings';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
 //Properties
 private selectedModule: ModuleItem;
 private selectedSubModule: NavItem;
 private availableSubModules: NavItem[];
 private availableModules: ModuleItem[] = [
  {
   iconSrc: "images/Logo.png",
   items: [{
    text: "Dashboard", routerLink: "/"
   }]
  }];

 private routeModule: ModuleItem = this.availableModules[0];
 private showNavigation: boolean = false;
 private config: AppSettings = null;
 private frontEndUrl: string;
 public configIsReady: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<string>();

 //Events
 actionBarUpdated: EventEmitter<any[]> = new EventEmitter<any[]>();
 moduleSwitched: EventEmitter<ModuleItem> = new EventEmitter<ModuleItem>();
 navigationBarUpdated: EventEmitter<NavItem[]> = new EventEmitter<NavItem[]>();
 headerBarUpdated: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
 navigationSwitcherChanged: EventEmitter<boolean> = new    EventEmitter<boolean>();

 moduleRegistered: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
 moduleUnRegistered: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

 constructor(
  @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document,
  private router: Router,
  private http: Http) {

  this.frontEndUrl = document.location.host;

  //Registriere alle gefundenen Module in den Header
  this.configIsReady.subscribe(() => {
   for (var module of this.config.modules) {
    this.registerModule(module);
   }
  });

  //TODO: Anstatt aus den Modulen zu laden muss das Module selbst die   Navigation angeben
  router.events
   .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
   .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
    this.getSubRoutes(event, router);
   });
 }

 //Initialisierungsfunktion für die Konfiguration
 initializeConfig(): Promise<AppSettings> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   //Hole die Konfiguration vom Webserver
   this.http
    .get("http://" + this.frontEndUrl + "/api/AppSettings") 
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
    data => {

     //Speichere die Konfiguration im Service
     this.config = data;

     //Lade für jedes Modul per Lazyload und füge das Modul in die Routerkonfiguration
     for (var module of this.config.modules) {
      this.router.config.push({
       path: module.toLowerCase(), loadChildren: this.lazyLoad(module)
      });
     }
     this.configIsReady.emit();
     resolve(data);
    },
    err => {
     console.log('ERROR!!!', err);
     reject(err);
    });
  });
 }

 //Geibt die aktuelle Konfiguration zurück
 getConfig(): AppSettings {
  return this.config;
 }

 //Helper für LazyLoad
 private lazyLoad(moduleName: string): () => any {
  let loader = () => new Promise(resolve => {
   (require as any).ensure([], require => {
    resolve(require('../Modules/' + moduleName + '/module')["Module"]);
   })
  });

  return loader;
 }
}
```

Does anybody know how what i am doing wrong?

Edit: Ok, i found out that the Router in AppService causes the cyclic dependency because it uses Http but i dont know how i can fix this.